# Como fazer um pesquisa em c#?

Tags: c#

Estou com algumas dificuldade em fazer um pesquisa como ilustra a imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando comboBox funcionou, eis aqui o código

Classe

```
 public void pesquisar(int ID)
        {
            Artigo List = new Artigo();
            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(caminho);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conexao;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            string obj = "Select * From artigo Where id_artigo=@id_artigo";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_artigo", ID);
            cmd.CommandText = obj;
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            conexao.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                id_artigo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_artigo"]);
                item = dr["item"].ToString();
                tipo_item = dr["tipo_item "].ToString();
                preco_compra = Decimal.Parse(dr["preco_compra"].ToString());
                preco_venda = Decimal.Parse(dr["preco_venda"].ToString());

            }
        }
```

Formulario

```
public void pesquisa_Detalhada()
        {
            Artigo obj = new Artigo();
            obj.pesquisar(Convert.ToInt32(cb_Artigo.SelectedValue));
            txt_Item.Text = obj.item.ToString();
            txt_Tipo_Item.Text = obj.tipo_item.ToString();
            txt_preco_vend.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(obj.preco_venda).ToString();
        }
```

Comment: podes meter o código onde vais buscar o texto presente na textbox?

Comment: o método `pesquisar(int ID)` está dentro da classe `Artigo` ? poste seu código por favor

Comment: tentei subistituir aqui: obj.pesquisar(txt_codigo_barra.Text).ToString(); e nada

Answer (score 0):

Considerando o método Pesquisar dentro da classe Artigo, ele deveria estar assim:

```
 public static Artigo Pesquisar(int _id)
 {
        Artigo obj = new Artigo();
        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(caminho);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conexao;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        string sql = "Select * From artigo Where id_artigo=@id_artigo";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_artigo", _id);
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        conexao.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            obj.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_artigo"]);
            obj.Item = dr["item"].ToString();
            obj.TipoItem = dr["tipo_item "].ToString();
            obj.PrecoCompra = Decimal.Parse(dr["preco_compra"].ToString());
            obj.PrecoVenda = Decimal.Parse(dr["preco_venda"].ToString());
        }

       conexao.Close();

       return obj;
 }
```

Agora para executar a pesquisa, Execute assim:

```
public void PesquisaDetalhada()
{
     //Usando um TextBox para informar o ID
     Artigo obj = Artigo.Pesquisar(Convert.ToInt32(txbId.Text))
     txt_Item.Text = obj.Item;
     txt_Tipo_Item.Text = obj.TipoItem;
     txt_preco_vend.Text = obj.PrecoVenda.ToString("C2");
}
```

Um detalhe é que no `comboBox` você pesquisa pelo ID, no TextBox você pesquisa pelo código de barras, repare que em códigos de barras você pode ter normalmente 13 dígitos, o que estouraria o tamanho máximo de uma variável `int`, será necessário adequar essa situação. Repare também no padrão de nomenclatura.

Comment: ok, gratos pela ajuda